# Uncaught TypeError: array.map is not a function

Tags: javascript

My code:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];

array = new Proxy(array, {
  get(target, prop) {
    return Reflect.get(target, prop > 1 ? 1 : 2);
  }
});

array.map() // Uncaught TypeError: array.map is not a function
```

How do I make all array methods remain available (after `Proxy`)?

Comment: What do you think get returns for array.map?!

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve here? It's not really clear.

Comment: You've got a `get()` handler, and the expression `array.map` means "get the value of the property called 'map' from the target".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could solve this problem would be to check if the property is a number before applying your custom processing step. For example like this:

```js
array = [1, 2, 3];

array = new Proxy(array, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(prop))) {
      return Reflect.get(target, prop > 1 ? 1 : 2);
    }
    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
  }
});

console.log(typeof array.map);
```

Comment: The get method receives prop as a string (or as a Symbol), that's why I chose this slightly awkward check for numbers.

Comment: Ah yes, fair enough